# Fix specific CSS positioning issue

Tags: php, html, css

I'm currently designing and coding a website and I ran into a problem with the CSS. I've been at this for a few hours now and it's really giving me a hard time I can't figure out what is messing it up. I've tried many different ideas but nothing works. At this moment I would even accept a stupid workaround because I want to continue with the other pages.

Go on cvheaven.com/contact.php to see the problem. If you go to cvheaven.com you see the footer works great, but here it's messed up. I'm attaching the main contact.php file and all of the css in one place along with the footer.php file. Please tell me what you think!

http://shrib.com/linkstofiles

Comment: Post the HTML/CSS for the specific problem you have here.

Answer (score 3):

Give your `<footer>`  tag an `overflow: hidden;`

Then give it `top: 150px` and give the `id "end"` `top: 150px;`

It's not the cleanest solution, but it looks better.
I hope this is what you meant.

**EDIT**

Look at Alex Wright's answer, it`s also a solution, i would even say it's the better one. How i said, it's hard to find the right thing quickly without having more of the code :)

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked beautifully,and it didn't even mess up my homepage footer. Thanks again. How did you even think of that? Do you have any idea what was causing that?

Comment: well i think there is a little bit of mess in the code, a mix of inline-CSS and external CSS. It's hard to say by just see it in browser. But i wouldnt work so much with the top-attribute, i think it's not that good doing it everywhere. The elements should look like this without top: xx;

If the code is written clearly the elements should nicely float among themselves and you just have to add a bit of margin.

Answer (score 1):

You may find that cleaning up any errors in your code will help, you can see a full list here right in W3C's free validator.

https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fcvheaven.com%2Fcontact.php

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're seeing this happen is because the `input` elements within the form are floated.

You simply need to clear the float on the `form` tag, and your footer columns will display correctly.

I would give your form a classname:

`<form class="contact-form">`

and then clear the float with CSS

`.contact-form::after {
        content: '';
        clear: both;
        display: table;
    }`